# Where can i see my data in Hadoop HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I set the dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir in master and slave nodes as /home/hduser/hadoop/hdfs/name 
/home/hduser/hadoop/hdfs/data 
I copy the file from local disk to HDFS. 
Where can i see that file data in HDFS

Comment: Asking same question at multiple places won't help much Shekhar. You can instead spend sometime on reading. Asking the same question repeatedly is not gonna change the answer. And, if you are trying to verify the answers, it's good. But for that go through some authentic documents instead of asking here n there. Just google HDFS, you'll get tons of useful links. Please don't take it otherwise.

Comment: You are right. Multiple people give multiple answers and suggestions. But thank you for your advise...

Answer (score 1):

These configuration parameters determine where in the local filesystem Hadoop stores its image and raw data. When you import file data into HDFS, it dosen't involve these values. In general, data is written into HDFS at the path you specify (when it is absolute), or a path qualified by your username (by default, I believe, this is `/user/your_username`) when you use a relative path.

So, if I have a file named `example` in my (local) home directory and say

```
local:~ matt> hadoop fs -put example relative/path
```

I should be able to find it in HDFS at `/user/matt/relative/path/example`. On the other hand, if I do this

```
local:~ matt> hadoop fs -put example /absolute/path/in/hdfs
```

it will be in HDFS at `/absolute/path/in/hdfs/example`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, then. You have a file in the local filesystem that you write into HDFS, and the contents of that file becomes blocks of a certain size within HDFS. The fsimage (which is written on the NameNode in the value of `dfs.name.dir`) keeps track of which blocks correspond to the representation of that file, and the binary data that constitutes those blocks is written to some set of DataNodes (depending on the replication factor). But that's the only notion of the "file" as far as HDFS is concerned. What are you trying to see?